# dbcon = sqlite3.connect(sys.argv[1] + '.sqlite') . meaning?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, dbconnection

I have a python program, I need to know what does the following block of code does.

particularly the dbcon=sqlite3.connect command. What are the parameters in the parenthesis.

```
    dbcon = sqlite3.connect(sys.argv[1] + '.sqlite')
    dbcurs = dbcon.cursor()

    dbcurs.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS acc''')
    dbcurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE acc (time REAL, x INTEGER, y INTEGER, z INTEGER)''')
    dbcurs.execute('''CREATE INDEX time_hash ON acc (time)''')
```

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` holds the command line arguments passed to the python script. So `sys.argv[1]` would be the first argument after the name of the script, which is `sys.argv[0]`. I assume that this argument is the location of a sqlite database, minus the .sqlite extension. See the docs for the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) and [sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) modules.

For example, if you typed `python myscript.py /path/to/my/db` into the command line, where myscript.py is the name of your script, the line `dbcon = sqlite3.connect(sys.argv[1] + '.sqlite')`would try to open a database connection for a database file located at "/path/to/my/db.sqlite".